# Are there still reasons to use lazy_static?

Tags: rust, lazy-static

[lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) is a very popular crate. Years ago, it had no better alternatives for certain tasks. But today, are there still any reasons to choose `lazy_static` over [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) (from the standard library, as of Rust 1.70), the [once_cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell) crate, or the upcoming [`LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html)?

Answer (score 9):

If you need the code to run on `#![no_std]` platforms that do not have OS-level support for blocking, **and** guarantee that the initialization routine is only executed once, you may still need to use `lazy_static`. As per [the `once_cell` documentation](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/#faq) :

> #### Does this crate support `no_std`?
>
> Yes, but with caveats. `OnceCell` is a synchronization primitive which semantically relies on blocking....
>
> Waiting fundamentally requires OS support.... You *could* make code to compile by blindly using pure spinlocks, but the runtime behavior would be subtly wrong.

`once_cell` achieves `no_std` support using either the `race` or `critical-section` features. `race` only supports platforms with atomic pointers, and risks calling the initialization routine multiple times across different threads. `critical-section` requires specific hardware and/or OS support from the [critical_section](https://crates.io/crates/critical_section) crate.

On the other hand, `lazy_static`'s `no_std` implementation uses spinlocks, so it should build for any platform without the risk of racy initialization. The author of the `once_cell` crate has published [an article](https://matklad.github.io/2020/01/02/spinlocks-considered-harmful.html) explaining what is meant by "subtly wrong" behavior, which may need special care to avoid as well.

Note that these requirements are extremely specific and won't apply to most use-cases. `once_cell` should be sufficient for everything else.

Comment: This answer is out of date. The `once_cell` documentation now literally says: "Don’t use `lazy_static`."

Comment: Just submitted an edit to address the newer documentation.

Answer (score 6):

`once_cell` and `LazyLock` have a minimum support version of the compiler. For earlier versions of it you would probably want to stick to `lazy_static` which has served it purpose pretty well when less features were available.